# Docker daemon "--add-host" globally

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, containers

I already tried asking this on the docker forums but didn't find a solution. Maybe this question has already been answered but hopefully this helps someone else with the same issue.

**tl;dr:** Is it possible to set `--add-host=docker01.company.lan:host-gateway` globally? For example in /etc/docker/daemon.json

**Why do I want/need to do that?**

At my company we use java containers with eureka that use the hostname of the docker host + the port binding to access services dynamically. Currently we work around this issue by adding extra_hosts to the stack but it would be much easier to just set it globally on each docker host.

**Steps to reproduce:**

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Docker version: 20.10.12, build e91ed57

**Stacks:**

doesn't work:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - '30004:80'
  busybox:
    image: busybox
    command: "watch -n 5 wget --spider http://docker01.company.lan:30004"
```

works:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - '30004:80'
  busybox:
    image: busybox
    extra_hosts:
      - docker01.company.lan:host-gateway
    command: "watch -n 5 wget --spider http://docker01.company.lan:30004"
```

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Technically you could use the "hosts" key in the `daemon.json`, but there seems to be a long standing issue with that --> https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/76